# How can i filter text using sed or awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a huge word-list file. I want to remove numeric only lines.

Can I do this using `sed` or something else?

Input:

```
Pass123
Dexg43
111116
246814
dancer@
Cody1234
Cody1234
```

Expected Output:

```
Pass123
Dexg43
dancer@
Cody1234
Cody1234
```

I need lines with 11116 and 246814 removed, the rest are ok.

Comment: Include sample input and output, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: you can also use grep - https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+-v and https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Regular-Expressions

Answer (score 1):

- sed

  ```
  sed '/^[0-9][0-9]*$/d' file
  sed '/^[0-9]\+$/d' file       # with gnu sed
  ```
- awk

  ```
  awk '$0!~/^[0-9]+$/' file
  ```
- grep

  ```
  grep -v '^[0-9][0-9]*$' file
  grep -v '^[0-9]\+$' file      # with gnu extension
  ```
- perl

  ```
  perl -ne 'print if !/^[0-9]+$/' file
  ```

Output:

```
Pass123
Dexg43
dancer@
Cody1234
Cody1234
```